# Why does the wiki claim that ROS packages using gazebo must be catkin packages?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The wiki claims that ROS packages depending on gazebo have to be catkin (wet) packages, and not rosbuild (dry) packages.

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Overview_of_new_ROS_integration#Catkin

But if you're using the "standalone" gazebo APIs you can just access whatever you need using cmake either way.  If you're using APIs from any of the ROS catkin (wet) packages in the gazebo_ros_packages metapackage you can still depend on those packages from a rosbuild (dry) package (dry can depend on wet, it's wet that can't depend on dry).

Is this an error, or am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4405/why-does-the-wiki-claim-that-ros-packages-using-gazebo-must-be-catkin-packages?/) by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/496/leblanc_kevin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

@leblanc_kevin, I believe you are right. The statement that

> you will first need to "catkinize" your packages to begin migration

is probably not true. A more correct way to phrase it would probably be that while both rosbuild and catkin work at the moment, rosbuild is slowly being deprecated in favor of catkin, and the rest of the tutorial assumes that you're using catkin.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried using Gazebo 1.9 on Hydro myself yet, neither with rosbuild nor with catkin, but I assume that it doesn't behave differently than other catkin packages, which work fine with rosbuild.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 226 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/496/leblanc_kevin/) on 2013-10-09**:
Thanks, that's what I wanted to confirm.  I know rosbuild is deprecated, but the status of that deprecation is not visible in much of the documentation, and there are many inconsistent and erroneous pieces of documentation scattered around the ros.org site.  I think it's important to try to keep documentation accurate, which is why I pointed out what I thought was an error.  The wiki should recommend catkinization, and it should explain that this is because of the deprecation of rosbuild.